# <c:if> not working in JSTL

Tags: jsp, jstl

In my jsp I try to compare two integers but the comparison does not work for c:if:

```
<c:set var="test" value="1" scope="request" />
<c:choose>
    <c:when test = "${test == 1}">
            it works
    </c:when>
</c:choose>
<c:if test="${test == 1} ">
   does not work        
</c:if>
```

Comment: Try exactly following documented/authoritative code snippets. Whitespace is significant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove the extra space after the closing bracket, there should be no space there.

```
<c:if test="${test eq 1}">
   does not work        
</c:if>
```